# Error: 'There was a problem connecting to the CUPS server.'after upgrade 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: networking, printing, samba

After upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10, I can not use my (SAMBA) network printer anymore. Jobs stay in the que forever.
When I go to 'Printers' and ask for the properties of the printer, I get the message: "There was a problem connecting to the CUPS server".

In Firefox I can browse localhost:631 (as mentioned in another post on this forum, not from me) and the printer is visible.
When trying to print a test page from there, I get another error message: Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED. For me, this is totally uncomprehensible.

With 14.04 and before, it worked like a charm. I have tried to install the printer again, to no avail. The printserver is not found, the printer not seen.

(And, not related, but my computer is a lot slower since this 'upgrade'. Think I'll go back to 14.04. Wish I had made an image of my harddisk, as a usually do before any upgrade. Until now, every upgrade went smooth, so I figured I could skip this time. And of course...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List the iptable configuration with the command

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Then use the following script to open CUPS connection on the port 631

**## open cups (printing service) udp/tcp port 631 for LAN users ##**

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
```

**Allow all inbound cups requests.**

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp  --destination-port 631  -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp  --destination-port 631  -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreciate your efford, Vembu!

Comment: I really appreciate your efford, Vembu! But this does not help either. At first I just copy/pasted the lines in a terminal (BTW, sudo is needed), but then I realised my network was not in the 192.168.0.x range but 192.168.147.x, so I adapted the lines before entering them. (Now I have 2 entries in iptables that I don't want, how to get rid of them? Time to use man, I guess :-) ). When I ask for the properties of the printer I still get the same message: "There was a problem connecting to the CUPS server". I have no time to try to reinstall the printer, I will have to do that tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like your suggestion worked. After reinstall, the 'old' printer still acts funny, but the freshly installed (not possible before your second advice) one works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That Sounds good :)

Comment: I think this should be filed as a bug because this is far from a user-friendly solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem very similar to yours: I had configured in my computer a remote printer and it worked in Ubuntu 14.04.  It stopped working after the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10.  Trying to view its properties resulted in the message "There was a problem connecting to the CUPS server".  The printer could be seen in localhost:631 but here we have a difference: I told it to print a test page and there was no error message; later I went to the printer and the test page was there.

And in my case, I then just removed and re-installed the printer, and then I was able to print to it.

So if anyone else has this problem, please start by removing and re-installing the printer.

Answer (score 0):

While you upgrade your machine from 14.04 to 14.10 packages which was referring the wireless printer would get differed and this is reason it was not showing your wireless printer.

Reinstall your printer which may fix this issue.

Also, Please check whether the new printer connection is trusted connection in your new firewall settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not a wireless printer and I have tried to install it again, which did not work. It might help If you can tell me how to check and/or alter mij firewall settings. In the dash no firewall turns up when I search for it, so I don't know where to look for it. TIA.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu 14.10 the printer has to been on line. That is Ubuntu must be able to make a connection. Otherwise it will fail (on my machine).